# TelosB configuration with GPS

Tags: gps, sensors, tinyos, nesc

how can you configure TelosB with GPS? Can you direct me to a link that can help me with programming the TelosB?

Comment: it is a wireless sensor mote

Answer (score 0):

TelosB mote doesn't come with GPS. But lately I have found this testbed (http://pharos.ece.utexas.edu/wiki/index.php/How_to_Analyze_the_TelosB_Signal_Strength_vs._Distance) which can be configured with TelosB. But it is certain that you need additional hardware to do that. Also, try this tutorial(http://www.ladyada.net/make/gpsshield/solder.html) to solder GPS into telosB just like he did for arduino.